# Pandas dataframe created in function not located by Python

Tags: python, function, pandas, dataframe

I have defined the following function to create a dataframe, based off three arguments: position, a list of metrics, minimum minutes played. (I am working with football match data.) The dataframe (cpd_df) is then queried using the PandaSQL package and this new dataframe is returned.

```
def create_positional_dfs(position, list_of_metrics, minimum_minutes):
    if position == 'DM':
        relevant_df = DMs
    elif position == 'AM':
        relevant_df = AMs
    else:
        relevant_df = master 
    cpd_df = pd.DataFrame(data=relevant_df, columns=list_of_metrics)
    cpd_query = """SELECT * FROM cpd_df WHERE [Total Mins] >= """ + str(minimum_minutes) + """ AND Position = '""" + position + """'"""
    return psql.sqldf(cpd_query, globals())
```

However, when inserting the following arguments:

```
create_positional_dfs('CM', ['Passes', 'Tackles', 'Total Mins'], 450)
```

I get the following error:

```
PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: cpd_df [SQL: "SELECT * FROM cpd_df WHERE [Total Mins] >= 450 AND Position = 'DM'"]
```

It appears Python is unable to find the cpd_df dataframe created in the function.

Is it not possible to create a Pandas dataframe within a function? What would be the best way of getting around this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the `globals` namespace, but your `cpd_df` is a *local variable*. Pass `locals` instead:

```
def create_positional_dfs(position, list_of_metrics, minimum_minutes):
    if position == 'DM':
        relevant_df = DMs
    elif position == 'AM':
        relevant_df = AMs
    else:
        relevant_df = master 
    cpd_df = pd.DataFrame(data=relevant_df, columns=list_of_metrics)
    cpd_query = """SELECT * FROM cpd_df WHERE [Total Mins] >= """ + str(minimum_minutes) + """ AND Position = '""" + position + """'"""
    return psql.sqldf(cpd_query, locals()) # use locals here
```